# Can you display a variable in a Drupal webform component label?

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to create a webform in Drupal 6 where the label of a select webform component is rendered using the contents of a variable.  For example:

client_name = "Starbucks"

and I would like the label of 5 or 5 different webform components to include "Starbucks".  I prefer to code this with a variable, as this webform will be cloned in the future.

Is there a way to do this?  From what I can tell, labels do not accept Drupal tokens and I'm not sure where to define the variable.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can alter form elements, including labels with [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). Use `dpm()` (from the Devel module) to inspect the `$form` array to find the value you want to change.